# Better way to delete every n-th element from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of 1000 elements. Now I need to delete the 1st, 2nd, 4th, 8th, 16th, 32nd, etc element from that list. Here's my solution

```
i = 0
while pow(2,i) < len(arr):
    del arr[pow(2,i) - 1 - i]
    i += 1
```

But I think it seems like some bad code. Is there more elegant way to get the same result?

Comment: So if the original list is `[a, b, c, d]`, should the result be `[c]` or `[c, d]` (which is what your code outputs)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to *reverse* your iteration; delete the powers from the highest value down. Start with the next highest power of two that's greater than the list length and shift down from there:

```
i = 2 ** len(arr).bit_length()  # next higher power-of-two > len
while i > 1:
    i >>= 1
    del arr[i - 1]  # 4th index is 3, 8th index is 7, etc.
```

Another alternative: rather than delete from the list in-place, you could generate a new list:

```
[v for i, v in enumerate(arr, 1) if i & (i - 1)]
```

This uses the fact that powers of two have just one bit set; if you mask that with the number - 1, you get zero.

Demos:

```
>>> arr = list(range(1, 33))  # 6 values to remove, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32
>>> arr
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
>>> len(arr)
32
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(arr, 1) if i & (i - 1)]
[3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
>>> i = 2 ** len(arr).bit_length()  # highest power-of-two >= len
>>> while i > 1:
...     i >>= 1
...     del arr[i - 1]  # 4th index is 3, 8th index is 7, etc.
...
>>> arr
[3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
>>> arr == [v for i, v in enumerate(range(1, 33), 1) if i & (i - 1)]
True
>>> len(arr)
26
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution using [`numpy.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html?highlight=delete)

Starting from an array, generated randomly with size, for example, `1000`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(100, size=(1000))
```

We begin by determining the maximum power of 2 within the size of the array:

```
max_power = np.ceil(np.log2(len(a)))
```

The content of `max_power` in this example is `10`.

Now we can create an array with the powers of two, representing the indices to delete:

```
exponents = np.arange(1, max_power)
indices = np.power(np.full(len(exponents), 2), exponents).astype(np.int)
```

The indices array contains `array([  2,   4,   8,  16,  32,  64, 128, 256, 512])`.

Now we can proceed to delete these indices:

```
result = np.delete(a, indices)
```

### Time comparison: numpy and list comprehension

```
%timeit np.delete(a, indices)
>>> 35.1 µs ± 2.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if i+1 not in powers_to_remove]
>>> 372 µs ± 25.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
powers_to_remove = [2**i for i in range(int(math.ceil(math.log(len(arr), 2))))]
result = [arr[i] for i in range(len(arr)) if i+1 not in powers_to_remove]
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey, you are right, I mixed the n'th position with the array index. Edited and solved. Thanks

Comment: This has to build a O(logN) list, then do a containment test against that list each step. That makes this a O(NlogN) solution with a O(logN) space requirement. You can easily achieve this in O(logN) time without any additional space!

Answer (score 0):

you could also iterate in reverse over the powers of 2:

```
mx = (len(arr) - 1).bit_length() - 1

for idx in (1 << i for i in range(mx, -1, -1)):
    del arr[idx]
```

`mx = (len(arr) - 1).bit_length() - 1` is the highest exponent of 2 you can remove.

`1 << i` is just `pow(2, i)` for integers.